# Botón con diferentes funciones en Android Studio (Chronometro)

Tags: android, botón

Estoy intentando hacer un cronometro con un solo botón que sea capaz de iniciar y parar con un `OnClickListener`, y reiniciar el cronometro con un `OnLongClickListener`.

Hasta ahora he conseguido hacerlo con varios botones a partir de una aplicación ya hecha, aunque no consigo hacerla funcionar.

```
package example.abhiandroid.chronometerexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Chronometer simpleChronometer;
    Button start, stop, restart, setFormat, clearFormat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // initiate views
        simpleChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.simpleChronometer);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        restart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restartButton);
        setFormat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setFormat);
        clearFormat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearFormat);
        // perform click  event on start button to start a chronometer
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                simpleChronometer.start();
            }
        });

        // perform click  event on stop button to stop the chronometer
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                simpleChronometer.stop();
            }
        });





        // perform click  event on restart button to set the base time on chronometer

        restart.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                simpleChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

                return true;    // <- set to true (siempre para long click)
            }
        });



//        restart.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
//
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//
//                simpleChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
//            }
//        });


        // perform click  event on set Format button to set the format of chronometer
        setFormat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                simpleChronometer.setFormat("Time (%s)");
            }
        });

        // perform click  event on clear button to clear the current format of chronmeter as you set through set format
        clearFormat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                simpleChronometer.setFormat(null);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Añado el XML por si lo necesitáis para algo:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/chronometerInAndroid"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/start" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stopButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/startButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/stop" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/restartButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/stopButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/restart" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/setFormat"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/restartButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/setFormat" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/clearFormat"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/setFormat"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/clearFormat" />
<!-- chronometer with black background and red text color -->
<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/simpleChronometer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/clearFormat"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#f00"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Además no se si sería posible con material design, que la propia tarjeta fuese el botón, o en su defecto, que cambiase el texto (en mi caso serán iconos) del botón cuando estuviese el cronometro encendido u apagado.

Gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La lógica que buscas podrías controlarlo con un simple `boolean`. Con una variable `boolean` podrás indicarle a tu programa si el cronómetro está parado o no, y así poder ejecutar un método u otro, tal que así:

```
Chronometer simpleChronometer;
Button start;
boolean parado = true;

start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (parado) {
                    simpleChronometer.start();
                    parado = false;
                } else {
                    simpleChronometer.stop();
                    parado = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Y para el `onLongClickListener` puedes hacérselo al propio botón `start` y así tener las tres opciones en el mismo botón:

```
start.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                simpleChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

                return true;    // <- set to true (siempre para long click)
            }
        });
```

Comment: No se me había ocurrido, la verdad, es muy lógico, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Para esto puedes definir un único botón que cambia de acuerdo al estado para detener/iniciar el cronometro, se puede guardar el estado mediante una variable de tipo boolean:

```
 private boolean isRunning;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.myChronometer);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!isRunning) {
                    myChronometer.start();
                    start.setText("Stop");
                    isRunning = true;
                }else{
                    myChronometer.stop();
                    start.setText("Start");
                    isRunning = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego ejemplo completo:

**[Android Chronometer.](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Chronometer)**