# ¿Como puedo hacer un cronometro con formato segundos, milisegundos?

Tags: android, android-studio

Necesito dos botones, iniciar y pausar, pero el formato default es de minutos, segundos y lo necesito en segundos, milisegundos.

Comment: Podrias añadir el codigo de lo que has intentado?En que te falla? Que errores te da?

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/62372/95 , ahí encontraras incluso el link de un ejemplo completo usando la clase Chronometer. @Ecolin100

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Cronometro extends JFrame implements Runnable, ActionListener
    {
public static int onoff = 0;
public Cronometro()
{
    setTitle("Cronometro");
    setSize( 300, 200 );
    setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

    //Etiqueta donde se colocara el tiempo 
    tiempo = new JLabel( "00:00:000" );
    tiempo.setFont( new Font( Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 50 ) );
    tiempo.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
    tiempo.setForeground( Color.BLUE );
    tiempo.setBackground( Color.WHITE );
    tiempo.setOpaque( true );

    add( tiempo, BorderLayout.CENTER );

    //Boton iniciar
    JButton btn = new JButton( "Iniciar" );
    btn.addActionListener( this );
    add( btn, BorderLayout.NORTH );

    //Boton reiniciar inicia nuevamente desde 0
    JButton btnP = new JButton( "Reiniciar" );
    btnP.addActionListener( this );
    add( btnP, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

    this.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    setVisible( true );
}

public void run(){
    Integer minutos = 0 , segundos = 0, milesimas = 0;
    //min es minutos, seg es segundos y mil es milesimas de segundo
    String min="", seg="", mil="";
    try
    {
        //Mientras cronometroActivo sea verdadero entonces seguira
        //aumentando el tiempo
        while( cronometroActivo )
        {
            Thread.sleep( 4 );
            //Incrementamos 4 milesimas de segundo
            milesimas += 4;

            //Cuando llega a 1000 osea 1 segundo aumenta 1 segundo
            //y las milesimas de segundo de nuevo a 0
            if( milesimas == 1000 )
            {
                milesimas = 0;
                segundos += 1;
                //Si los segundos llegan a 60 entonces aumenta 1 los minutos
                //y los segundos vuelven a 0
                if( segundos == 60 )
                {
                    segundos = 0;
                    minutos++;
                }
            }

            //Esto solamente es estetica para que siempre este en formato
            //00:00:000
            if( minutos < 10 ) min = "0" + minutos;
            else min = minutos.toString();
            if( segundos < 10 ) seg = "0" + segundos;
            else seg = segundos.toString();

            if( milesimas < 10 ) mil = "00" + milesimas;
            else if( milesimas < 100 ) mil = "0" + milesimas;
            else mil = milesimas.toString();

            //Colocamos en la etiqueta la informacion
            tiempo.setText( min + ":" + seg + ":" + mil );
        }
    }catch(Exception e){}
    //Cuando se reincie se coloca nuevamente en 00:00:000
    tiempo.setText( "00:00:000" );
}

//Esto es para el boton iniciar y reiniciar
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent evt ) {
    Object o = evt.getSource();
    if( o instanceof JButton )
    {
        JButton btn = (JButton)o;
        if( btn.getText().equals("Iniciar") ){
            if(onoff == 0){
               onoff = 1;
               iniciarCronometro();
            }
        }
        if( btn.getText().equals("Reiniciar") ) {
            if (onoff == 1){
               onoff = 0;
               pararCronometro();
            }
        }
    }
}

//Iniciar el cronometro poniendo cronometroActivo 
//en verdadero para que entre en el while
public void iniciarCronometro() {
    cronometroActivo = true;
    hilo = new Thread( this );
    hilo.start();
}

//Esto es para parar el cronometro
public void pararCronometro(){
    cronometroActivo = false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Esta parte es para look and feel por lo tanto es opcional, solo hay que descomentarla
    //try{
    //    UIManager.setLookAndFeel( new com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel() );
    //}catch( Exception e ){}
    new Cronometro();
}

JLabel tiempo;
Thread hilo;
boolean cronometroActivo;
```

A ver si te sirve, pero deberías poner el código que has intentado, para que podamos corregirlo nosotros.